# Using ampersand's (&) in JSON column formatting

Tags: list, custom-actions, special-characters, json-formatting, email-action

I am trying to use JSON to format a "Person" column in a Sharepoint list with an email action button.

I would like the email to contain a link to the Sharepoint list item in question, but the link contains ampersands (&).

Unfortunately the ampersand is a special character and chops the string after the 1st ampersand (as described [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4113/special-characters-specifically-ampersand-in-json-server-side-population-not-displaying-in-grid)). Is there a way to stop this by getting the & to be treated as a symbol rather than a special character?

Comment: `email action button` - do you mean `<a>` with `mailto:`?

Comment: Perhaps try the `replaceAll()` operator in [JSON column formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference), eg `replaceAll([$myColumnName], '&', '%26')`.  This works well when you know *specifically* what you are trying to find and replace, personally I am still looking for a solution that replaces ALL the characters that SharePoint needs to be encoded, there must be a smart regex-minded person out there who could figure that out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using URL encoding (percent encoding), replacing the `&` with `%26`. You can find all encoded characters on [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Comment: Are there any operators available in JSON column formatting that can URL encode a string to make it an acceptable value in a SharePoint list link?

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `&` with `%26` code in `mailto:`

You can refer below code:

```
<p>
    This is an email link:
    <a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again&body=Test%26Test" target="_top">Send Mail</a>
</p>
```

More details about URL Encoding you can refer [This](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You should encode only the body of your message. Use [this](https://www.mikemustaine.com/mmtools/files/mailTo.html) service to build your url. Fill in required fields and then copy the value of `href` attribute from `standard link` from Output section (**NOT** encoded one).

For example below formatting works well for me (I use current item ID to build the url):

```
{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "a",
    "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "='mailto:some@user.com?subject=Hello&body=https%3A//myurl.com%3Fparam1%3D1%26param2%3D2%26ID%3D' + [$ID] + '\n another text'"
    },
    "txtContent": "[$Title]"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint JSON formatting now supports `replace` and `replaceAll` operators which will help you to replace `&` with `%26`.

For example (using `replaceAll` operator):

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "=replaceAll([$Title], '&', '%26')",
    "style": {
        "font-weight": "bold"
    }
}
```

**References**:

1. [SharePoint: Replace All Occurrences of Substring in a String using JSON Formatting](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/08/22/sharepoint-replace-all-occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string-using-json-formatting/)
2. [JSON formatting syntax reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference)

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is to use operators and operands instead of a `+` on a single line

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "style": {
                "padding-right": "8px"
            },
            "txtContent": "@currentField.title"
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "attributes": {
                "iconName": "Mail",
                "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
                "href": {
                    "operator": "+",
                    "operands": [
                        "mailto:",
                        "@currentField.email",
                        "?subject=Task status&body=Hey, how is your task coming along?.\r\n---\r\n",
                        "@currentField.title",
                        "\r\nClick this link for more info. http://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ConferencePrep/Tasks/Prep/DispForm.aspx?ID=",
                        "[$ID]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```