# Dynamic URL generated by JSON column formatting breaks on ampersand character

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting, microsoft-lists

I am using [JSON column formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) to generate a dynamic URL based on the value in another column.

The dynamic URL is a link to a document library which is filtered by the value in the other column.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "style": {
        "margin-left": "0px"
      },
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "Click To View",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "='https://tenant-name.sharepoint.com/sites/site-name/cd/Forms/My%20View%20Name.aspx?env=WebViewList&FilterField1=My_x0020_Reference&FilterValue1=' + [$Title]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The links are displaying correctly when I hover over them with my mouse, eg:

```
https://tenant-name.sharepoint.com/sites/site-name/cd/Forms/My%20View%20Name.aspx?env=WebViewList&FilterField1=My_x0020_Reference&FilterValue1=A & B Services - A & B Family Trust
```

However when I click on them, they seem to break when there are ampersands `&` in the column value.

So clicking on the above link loads this URL (note the URL is cut short after `%20`):

```
https://tenant-name.sharepoint.com/sites/site-name/cd/Forms/My%20View%20Name.aspx?env=WebViewList&FilterField1=My_x0020_Reference&FilterValue1=A%20
```

I have previously used the site below to better understand encoding and decoding HTML entities:

https://mothereff.in/html-entities

Should I be encoding the column value when passing it into the dynamic URL, and if so how can I do that in JSON column formatting?

**Edit 1:**

Based on [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/264355), I tried replacing:

```json
"href": "='https://tenant-name.sharepoint.com/sites/site-name/cd/Forms/My%20View%20Name.aspx?env=WebViewList&FilterField1=My_x0020_Reference&FilterValue1=' + [$Title]"
```

with:

```json
"href": {
"operator": "+",
"operands": [
"https://tenant-name.sharepoint.com/sites/site-name/cd/Forms/My%20View%20Name.aspx?env=WebViewList&FilterField1=My_x0020_Reference&FilterValue1=",
"[$Title]"
]
}
```

But it produced the same result.

**Edit 2:**

When I use the filters panel in the target document library to filter for the same value, I can see that SharePoint has converted `&` to `%26` in the resulting URL.

So perhaps I need to somehow URL encode the column value before adding it to the dynamic URL?

Are there [any operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference) that can do this in JSON column formatting?

Perhaps `toString()` would encode the value?

Is there anyway to use `encodeURIComponent()` in JSON column formatting?

**Edit 3:**

I tried using the `replaceAll()` operator to replace `&` with `%26` and it seems to work.

Is there somehow I could use this approach to replace *ALL* the characters that SharePoint requires to be encoded?

```json
"href": "='https://tenant-name.sharepoint.com/sites/site-name/cd/Forms/My%20View%20Name.aspx?env=WebViewList&FilterField1=My_x0020_Reference&FilterValue1=' + replaceAll([$Title], '&', '%26')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no equivalent operator in JSON formatting to `encodeURIComponent()` function in JavaScript.

So, you need to replace all special characters that SharePoint requires to be encoded using the `replaceAll` operator.

**Reference**: [SharePoint: Replace All Occurrences of Substring in a String using JSON Formatting](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/08/22/sharepoint-replace-all-occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string-using-json-formatting/)

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to 1) Define an exhaustive list of all the characters SharePoint doesn’t like  2)  Use `replaceAlll()` to replace all those characters, not just one.

Comment: @pointerless, thanks for sharing it which will help others in future. 
user1063287, I know it is difficult to use `replaceAll` for all characters but not impossible AND we have to use this workaround for now because SharePoint JSON formatting does not support any equaivalent operator for `encodeURIComponent()` in JS.

Comment: This presently doesn't function for me, will debug then repost

Comment: Needed to escape a `'` `replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(@currentField, '%' , '%25'), ':', '%3A'), '/', '%2F'), '?', '%3F'), '#', '%23'), '[', '%5B'), ']', '%5D'), '@', '%40'), '!', '%21'), '$', '%24'), '&', '%26'), '\\'', '%27'), '(', '%28'), ')', '%29'), '*', '%2A'), '+', '%2B'), ',', '%2C'), ';', '%3B'), '=', '%3D'), ' ', '%20')`